# Remove laravel icon below

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

How to remove laravel below 
Please see image attached for reference
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you need to remove the icon please

Comment: can you share your page link

Comment: i just want to remove it because i want to display just the page without that thing @SagarGautam

Comment: It is only in local @SibasankarBhoi

Answer (score 3):

That icon is part of the [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) package. You either need to disable the package or uninstall it.

To disable it during runtime, use:

```
\Debugbar::disable();
```

and conversely, to enable use:

```
\Debugbar::enable();
```

Also, as noted in the documentation:

> The Debugbar will be enabled when APP_DEBUG is true.

Comment: how to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Also, it can be disabled in the file `.env`. If you have this file.

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```